# Tensorflow 2.0 : AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'matrix_band_part'

Tags: tensorflow2.0, attributeerror

While running the code tf.matrix_band_part , i get the following error

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'matrix_band_part'
```

My tensorflow version : 2.0

Any solution for this problem is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer. So i would like to share.

Compatible version for the function for tensorflow 2.0 is

```
tf.compat.v1.matrix_band_part
```

Ref : https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/band_part

Answer (score 0):

if someone find this issue, just try alternate version: `tf.linalg.band_part`